# Clear ng-src using ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem with clear `ng-src` (input file) using `ng-click`. I would like solve this problem using angular. I tried use `angular.element.val('')` but this is not good solution for me. Do you know another way?

controller.js

```
 app.imagePreview = false;

$scope.thumbnail = {
    dataUrl: null
};
$scope.fileReaderSupported = window.FileReader != null;
$scope.photoChanged = function(files){
    if (files != null) {
        var file = files[0];
        if ($scope.fileReaderSupported && file.type.indexOf('image') > -1) {
            $timeout(function() {
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                fileReader.onload = function(e) {
                    $timeout(function(){                            
                        $scope.thumbnail.dataUrl = e.target.result;
                        app.imagePreview = true;
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
app.clearImage = function(){
    $scope.thumbnail = {
        dataUrl: null
    };  
}
```

index.html

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
    <span class="input-group-btn">        
        <span class="btn btn-default btn-file add-img-upload">
            <a id="clearPreview" type="button" ng-click="product.clearImage()">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Usuń
            </a>
        </span>
        <span class="btn btn-default btn-file add-img-upload"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span> Wybierz 
            <input type="file" name="file" id="imgInp" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().photoChanged(this.files)" ng-model="files">
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
<img ng-if="product.imagePreview" ng-src="{{ thumbnail.dataUrl }}" id='img-upload'/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you've named the method app.clearImage and in your html, you're calling product.clearImage. Rename one of them so that they match and it should work.

I believe you really just want clearImage to be a method of your controller. Removing "product." in front of it in your html and chanding "app." in front of it in your controller to "$scope." should also work.

in your html:

and in your controller:

```
$scope.clearImage = function(){
    $scope.thumbnail = {
        dataUrl: null
    };  
}
```

Comment: I think this is correct, because my controller name 'product

Comment: If you're using controllerAs product, then you need to reference it as product.app.clearImage()

Comment: I see I above I don't insert, var app = this in my code

Comment: You have defined the function with app.clearImage = function()... that makes app part of the function name.